# Dynamic return type from library not working

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, dll

I have a library class which contains a method.

-> Create a class library project and post this method.

```
    public dynamic GetTrainRoute(string trainName)
    {
        //var list = new TrainDbManager().GetTrainRoute(dbConnection, trainName);
        //return list;

        var list = new []{new {TrainName = "Train A", RouteOrder = 1, From = "City A", To = "City B" } }.ToList();
        list.Add(new { TrainName = "Train A", RouteOrder = 2, From = "City B", To = "City C" });
        return list;
    }
```

I add reference of this library to my console project and when i call method

-> Now create a empty project, and add reference of library project into newly created project and now create instance of that class and call that method.

```
 Manager man = new Manager();
 var list = man.GetTrainRoute("Millat Up");
 string s;
 foreach (var v in list)
     s = v.TrainName; // <- exception throws here
```

[image]

It throw exception **'object' does not contain a definition for 'TrainName'** .When i hover on list, it contain list but when i try to retrieve that value , it throw exception. What i am doing here.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you post a complete sample which reproduces the problem? For brevity I tried in same project, Is this behavior only with class library ?

Answer (score 0):

To get this code to work, you should return a *list* of dynamic (`IList<dynamic>`).

In reality though, there is no reason to use anonymous types and `dynamic` here.  You should create a class to hold the train schedule information.

Additionally, your call will fail if no results are returned, because you can't `foreach` over `null`.  You should create an empty list, and subsequently add to that in your loop; if there are no results, the returned list will be empty.  You may also want to look into `yield return`.

Comment: im trying to save my self from creating too much classes. thats why i tried with dynamic.

Comment: what i do if it contain only two fields.?. SHould i create a class for that too.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that I should mention [this upfront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx):

> Using the `dynamic` keyword is not recommended except for certain
>   interop senerios.

Not only that but by using the dynamic keyword in the code snippet you provided, pretty much defeats the benifits of using a strongly typed language like c#.

I would recommend writing your own train class instead of generating it as an anonymous type:

> ```
> class Train
> {
>     public string TrainName { get; set; }
>     public int RouteOrder { get; set; }
>     public string From { get; set; }
>     public string To { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Then modifying your `GetTrainRoute` function to return an type:

> ```
> public List<Train> GetTrainRoute(string trainName)
> {
>     //var list = new TrainDbManager().GetTrainRoute(dbConnection, trainName);
>     //return list;
>     List<Train> TrainCollection = new List<Train>();
>     TrainCollection.Add(new Train() { TrainName = "Train A", RouteOrder = 1, From = "City A", To = "City B" });
>     TrainCollection.Add(new Train() { TrainName = "Train A", RouteOrder = 2, From = "City B", To = "City C" });
>
>     return TrainCollection;
> }
> ```

Your error should go away now. :) The problem is a result of mixing `dynamic` and `anonymous` types.

Comment: what i do if it contain only two fields.?. SHould i create a class for that too.

Comment: It is up to you, personally I don't go by the field count. I've written plenty of two field classes myself. I go by how reusable the data is. Something to keep in mind is anonymous types are mainly used for simplifying projections in linq queries.